# How to get Node.js to use non-pseudo-random number generator

Tags: node.js, random, cryptography

Given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033412/how-random-is-cryptorandombytes/43033592#43033592):

> Unless you have a **hardware random number generator**, the bytes will be pseudo-random—generated predictably from a seed value. The seed is generated from an OS-specific source (`/dev/urandom` on Unix-like systems, `CryptGenRandom` on Windows).

Wondering how you enable the use of a hardware random number generator in Node.js.

Comment: To which OS and which CPUs are you referring to? For Windows 10 on Intel see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/drng for Ubuntu Linux 13.x, x64 on Intel you have: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rdrand. And there might be other relevant libs.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the answer is saying? Unless you have unusual requirements you don't need a hardware random number generator.

Comment: I guess you could use a library like [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) to connect a hardware random number generator via serial port.

Comment: I think the question is meant in another way. nodejs is implicitly using a RNG in it's cryptography module, e.g. for Crypto.createECDH('prime256v1').generateKeys(). The question is: is then RNG hardware used? If yes, how can this be proven in a software certification process?