# How to speed up multiple crypto.randomBytes calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I will build a service which uses crypto.randomBytes() a lot. As I know it is blocking I/O. Is there a way to at least speed this process up? Is there anything multicores or multithreads can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details here: [How random is crypto#randomBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033412/how-random-is-cryptorandombytes)

Assuming you're not using windows `crypto.randomBytes()` is using `/dev/urandom`. There seem to be a few alternatives to using `/dev/urandom` if it's a performance bottleneck: https://serverfault.com/questions/6440/is-there-an-alternative-to-dev-urandom

Also no, /dev/urandom won't run multi-core: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160967

Comment: Thank you, links answered all of my questions.