# How to implement this encryption related code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption

I have following code in Java.

```
        String secretString = 'AAABBBCCC'
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom securerandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        securerandom.setSeed(secretString.getBytes());
        kgen.init(256, securerandom);
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");
        byte[] cryptograph = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);
        String enc1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cryptograph);
        return enc1;
```

I need to implement it in JavaScript/Node.js, however I can only figure out the last half in js like below

```
        'use strict';
        const crypto = require('crypto');
        const ALGORITHM = 'AES-256-ECB';
        const secretString = 'AAABBBCCC'

        // missing part in JS (how to convert secretString to key)

        function encrypt(plaintext, key) {
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, key, Buffer.alloc(0));
            return cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
        }
```

For the previous Java part( from **secretString** to **key** generated by **KeyGenerator**), I don't know how to implement it in JavaScript, neither do I know whether there is a thing like **KeyGenerator** in JavaScript world could help me to do the heavy lifting work.

Comment: Are you trying just trying to generate a key in JavaScript?

Comment: yup, however I don't quite understand how to do it in JS if I need to get same key like in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367907/generate-aes-key-on-node

Comment: @miradham yeah, it helps, but can't cover my issue completely, I've added a comment to the link you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
const crypto = require("crypto-js");


// Encrypt
const ciphertext = crypto.AES.encrypt('SOMETHING SECRET', 'secret key 123');

// Decrypt
const bytes  = crypto.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
const decryptedData = bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);

console.log(decryptedData);
```

https://runkit.com/mswilson4040/5b74f914d4998d0012cccdc0

**UPDATE**

JavaScript does not have a native equivalent for key generation. The answer is to create your own or use a third party module. I would recommend something like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you misunderstood the most important part from my question, which is from KEY to key in java code. Maybe I should update my question to make it easier understood.

Comment: So your question is how to obtain a value that lives in java from JavaScript??

Comment: nope, I don't understand how to implement the process (from secretString to key in Java) in JavaScript. Because what you posted is I've done in my JS code. btw, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`crypto.randomBytes()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback).
As per its documentation:

> Generates cryptographically strong pseudo-random data. The size argument is a number indicating the number of bytes to generate.

Also, it uses openssl's `RAND_bytes` API [behind scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033412/how-random-is-cryptorandombytes)